# Delete dynamic row in table using angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete dynamic `<tr>` using Angular. But my try was not success. I cant find what is error for this.

page.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async; let i =index;">
   <td>{{ row.code.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.desc.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
   <td style="float: right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" (click)="deleteRow(i)">Delete</i></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

page.component.ts

```
selectedOptions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){
}

deleteRow(index) {  
  if(this.selectedOptions$.value.length ==1) {
      return false;  
  } else {
      this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1);
```

}
}

Comment: Since the rows are returned by a `BehaviorSubject`, you should modify its source on `deleteRow`, so that it does not emit the row at the deleted index anymore.

Comment: @ConnorsFan How can I change my code to do it. I am fresher to Angular

Answer (score 0):

My english is very poor. 
you have put **(click)=deleteRow(i)>**
I think that only you need add double quotes in button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" (click)="deleteRow(i)"></i> Delete</button>
```

Try that or this for solve this issue.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`You need to add text to your <i> element or add click event to button element.
you can get values from behaviorsubject using value property`

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async; let i =index;">
  <td>{{ row.code }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.desc }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
  <td style="float: right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
      <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" 
      (click)="deleteRow(i)">Delete</i></button>
  </td>
```

`deleteRow(index) {

    if(this.selectedOptions$.value.length ==1) {

      // this.toastr.error("Can't delete the row when there is only one row", 'Warning');

        return false;

    } else {
        this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1);
      // this.toastr.warning('Row deleted successfully', 'Delete row');

        return true;

    }

  }`

Comment: whats the error you are getting? I tested this code. working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Behavior Subject, after you have spliced the value.

Something like this:

```
deleteRow(index) {  
  if(this.selectedOptions$.value.length ==1) {
      return false;  
  } else {
      const updatedoptions = this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1); 
      this.selectedOptions$.next(updatedOptions);
  }
```